# Override html tag auto close in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have turned on the auto-close feature for html tags in Notepad++, but in some situations I do not want Notepad++ to automatically insert the closing tag. Is there a way to override the auto-close function in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

Just go to `Settings > Preferences > Auto-Completion`
then un-tick the box saying `html/xml tag close`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I'm looking for a quick temporary override. I don't want to disable the feature since I do need it 95% of the time. For those other 5% I would like to be able to hold down a key (ALT perhaps) to override this behavior. But maybe such override functionality doesn't exist in Notepad++.

Comment: oh ok maybe you could use `macros` ?